Docker Image Pull Failed with error "image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform" on Azure Devops "windows-latest"
While trying to build the below Docker Image in Azure DevOps using the Microsoft hosted agent "windows-latest" or "windows-2019" getting below error

Docker file content is
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

# Install Powershell
RUN powershell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine"

# Install Nuget package provider
RUN powershell -Command "Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force -Scope AllUsers"

WORKDIR /azp/

COPY ./start.ps1 ./

CMD powershell .\start.ps1

Devops Pipeline YAML
pool:
  vmImage: windows-2019

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:  
    - job: BuildWindows
      steps:
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'XXXXXX'
          scriptType: 'bash'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: az acr build --image devops/windows:latest --registry registryName --no-push .
          workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/images/windows'

Did tried changing the agent from "windows-latest" to "windows-2019" but of no help
Also, after further research found out that windows-latest or any windows agent has by default use Linux container. So is there any way to switch container to windows in Microsoft hosted agents?

I can reproduce the same issue when using the az acr build command to build windows image.

By default, the command will use linux OS to build the docker image.
To solve this issue, you need to add the --platform windows argument to the az acr build command.
For example:
az acr build --image devops/windows:latest --registry xx --platform windows --no-push .

Yaml sample:
pool:
  vmImage: windows-2019

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:  
    - job: BuildWindows
      steps:
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'XXXXXX'
          scriptType: 'bash'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: az acr build --image devops/windows:latest --registry xx --platform windows --no-push .
          workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/images/windows'

Result:

For more detailed info, you can refer to the doc: az acr build

Thanks @kevin-lu-msft it resolved the issue, i could not find any documentation over the internet with respect to DevOps pipeline and you helped. Hope this will help others as well :)

If you could help explain, is --platform windows does the same thing as manually switching container in Docker Desktop?

@FarazAhmad Yes. The --platform is similar to the step to manually switching container. But not the same.  az acr build sends the build to Tasks. The actual build is running on a shared agent pool managed by Tasks. It's different from Microsoft-hosted DevOps agent.  It does not actually build the docker image directly in the Pipeline agent. When you add the argument --platform , this means that you need to use the windows shared pool. Here is a github ticket: https://github.com/Azure/acr/issues/627#issuecomment-1164823149 It will be helpful to understand the command.
